# Properties of the 2D Fourier Transform for Real Functions

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

In the context of the 1D Fourier transform, for a real function $f(x)$, the Fourier transform has a property: $F(\omega) = F^*(-\omega)$. This implies that the real part of the Fourier transform is an even function, while the imaginary part is an odd function.

I am attempting to generalize this property to 2D functions but am encountering difficulties. To illustrate, consider the following matrix as an example:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Using NumPy (in python) for the Fast Fourier Transform, I printed out the imaginary part of the result:

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
0.0 & 2.0 & 0.0 & -2.0 \\
0.0 & -2.0 & 2.0 & 0.0 \\
0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 \\
0.0 & 0.0 & -2.0 & 2.0 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Contrary to my expectations, the output was not symmetrical. I am seeking guidance to understand the properties of the Fourier transform of a real function in 2D space.

Answer (score 0):

I found it.
The property is as follow: $F(i, j) = F^*(-i, -j)$. In my example the $(0, 0)$ of Fourier transformed is set to be the zero value at $(3, 2)$.